# How to change string representation in django

Tags: django

I have model with a **str** function

```
person = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
    queryset=Person.objects.all(),
    widget=CustomCheckboxSelectMultiple, ///--> this is a Custom field
    required=False,
)

def __str__(self):
    return f"{self.first_name} {self.last_name}"
```

//output for example foo bar

Now i a specific form with a dropdown menu filled with the model above. In the dropdown menu the options are showed as the **str** from the model (sow foo bar). In this model however i want to show only the lastname.
How can ik change the **str** function for just this form ?

Answer (score 1):

Per the documentation you can create a custom field, subclassing the Model Choice Field. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#modelchoicefield

> The **str**() method of the model will be called to generate string
> representations of the objects for use in the field’s choices. To
> provide customized representations, subclass ModelChoiceField and
> override label_from_instance. This method will receive a model object
> and should return a string suitable for representing it. For example:

```
from django.forms import ModelChoiceField

class MyModelChoiceField(ModelChoiceField):
    def label_from_instance(self, obj):
        return f"{obj.last_name}"
```

EDIT: after additional information provided.

Same solution should work. It's not the widget you want to override. ModelMultipleChoiceField inherits ModelChoiceField (see in [django/forms/models.py](https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/forms/models.py#LL1558C50-L1558C50)). In your case:

```
from django.forms import ModelMultipleChoiceField

class MyModelMultipleChoiceField(ModelMultipleChoiceField):
    def label_from_instance(self, obj):
        return f"{obj.last_name}"

...
# the custom bit is the MyModelMultipleChoiceField, not the widget
person = forms.MyModelMultipleChoiceField(
    queryset=Person.objects.all(),
    widget=CustomCheckboxSelectMultiple, 
    required=False,
)
```

Comment: Tx, i know. Realised my question is not complete. The field is already a CustomField, i put more info in my question.